# difference between $S^2$, $\sigma_x^2$. and $\sigma^2$?

Tags: statistics, expected-value, standard-deviation, sampling

On $(5),$ $(6),$ and $(7),$ what's the difference between $S^2$ and $\sigma_x^2$?

Also, why does:

$$\sigma_X^2 = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^2} \sigma^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$

?

I'm assuming $\sigma^2$ is the population variance.

It seems like S is a random variable since I can take the expectation of it, but,  $\sigma_x$ is the same thing except not a random variable?

---

Let $(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ be a random sample of $X$ having unknown mean $\mu$, and variance $\sigma_x^2$

\begin{align}
S^2 &= \frac{1}{n} \sum (X_i - \bar{X})^2 \tag{0}\\[4ex]
E[S^2] &= E\Big[\frac{1}{n} \sum (X_i - \bar{X})^2 \Big]\tag{1}\\[2ex]
&= E\Bigg[\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\Big[~[(X_i - \mu)-(\bar{X}-\mu)]^2~\Bigg]\tag{2}\\[2ex]
&= E\Bigg[ \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \Big[~(X_i-\mu)^2-2(X_i-\mu)(\bar{X}-\mu)+(\bar{X}-\mu)^2~\Big] ~\Bigg]\tag{3}\\[2ex]
&= E\Bigg[~\frac{1}{n} \Big[~\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \mu)^2 - n(\bar{X} - \mu)^2 \Big]~\Bigg]\tag{4}\\[2ex]
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} E\big[(X_i-\mu)^2\big] - E\big[(\bar{X}-\mu)^2\big]\tag{5}\\[2ex]
&= \sigma^2 - \sigma_X^2\tag{6}\\[2ex]
&= \sigma^2 - \frac{1}{n}\sigma^2\tag{7}\\[2ex]
&= \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2\tag{8}
\end{align}

Equation (8) shows that $S^2$ is a biased estimator of $\sigma^2$

Comment: The first, at least is easy.  Since both n and $\sigma$ are independent of i,  $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2}\sigma^2= \frac{1}{n^2}\sigma \left(\sum_{i=1}^n 1\right)= \frac{1}{n^2}\sigma (n)= \frac{\sigma}{n}$.

Comment: In equation 6, is it possible that the subscript $X$ should actually be $\bar{X}$? Because that sure looks like what's being computed: the standard deviation of the mean (i.e., the term after the minus-sign in equation 5).

Comment: Its what the workbook says...

Answer (score 2):

$\sigma$ is the population standard deviation of the random variable $X$.

$X_i$ represents the value of the i-th sample. If you have $n$ different such samples, the standard deviation of the $n$ samples is the random variable $S$.

The average of a $n$ samples is the random variable $\bar{X}$. This variable will have a standard deviation $\sigma_X$.

Answer (score 2):

You may find your answers both in the *sample variance* subheading of the [variance entry in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance), or possibly in this [answer in Stack Exchange CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100050/67822).

> Difference between $\sigma_X^2$ and $S^2:$

The **standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the sample mean (standard error of the mean)** is

$$\sigma_{\bar X}^2 = \frac 1 n E\left( \bar X - \mu \right)^2$$

and it carries a bar on top of the subscripted random variable $\sigma_{\color{red}{\bar X}}^2.$

The **sample variance** is

$$\sigma_X^2=\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2$$

while the **unbiased sample variance (Bassel's correction)** is

$$S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2$$

although the $S^2$ notation applied to both of the above is most common.

> Why $\sigma_X^2 = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^2} \sigma^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$?

Probably, the right expression with the above bar on top of the $X$ should be:

$$\sigma_{\bar X}^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$

with $\sigma^2$ representing the population variance.

> It seems like $S$ is a random variable since I can take the expectation of it, but, $\sigma_x$ is the same thing except not a random variable?

A [statistic is an observable random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistic) - a quantity computed from a sample. Both would be random variables.

---

Re-stating the equations in the OP with the caveats above, and going along with symbols in the OP which expresses $\sigma_X^2$ as $S^2,$

$$
\small
\begin{align}
\color{red}{\sigma_X^2} (\text{or }S^2) &= \frac{1}{n} \sum (X_i - \bar{X})^2 \tag{0}\\[4ex]
E[\color{red}{\sigma_X^2}] &= E\Big[\frac{1}{n} \sum (X_i - \bar{X})^2 \Big]\tag{1}\\[2ex]
&= E\Bigg[\frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\Big[~[(X_i - \mu)-(\bar{X}-\mu)]^2~\Bigg]\tag{2}\\[2ex]
&= E\Bigg[ \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \Big[~(X_i-\mu)^2-2(X_i-\mu)(\bar{X}-\mu)+(\bar{X}-\mu)^2~\Big] ~\Bigg]\tag{3}\\[2ex]
&= E\Bigg[~\frac{1}{n} \Big[~\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - \mu)^2 - n(\bar{X} - \mu)^2 \Big]~\Bigg]\tag{4}\\[2ex]
&= \frac{1}{n} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} E\big[(X_i-\mu)^2\big] - E\big[(\bar{X}-\mu)^2\big]\tag{5}\\[2ex]
&= \sigma^2 - \sigma_{\color{red}{\bar X}}^2\tag{6}\\[2ex]
&= \sigma^2 - \frac{1}{n}\sigma^2\tag{7}\\[2ex]
&= \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$